# SYBASE 17 - Insert result set into Temp Table from sp_columns

Tags: stored-procedures, sybase, temp-tables, sqlanywhere

I'm new to Sybase but familiar with MS SQL Server. I'm trying to take the results from `sp_columns` and put it into a temp table. What is the proper syntax for this?

So far I have the below code but it's not working (error below).

```
CALL sp_columns('TableName')( et_result => #ColumnListing) WITH OVERVIEW;
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

--Edited to include error detail and code.

Comment: please update the question with more details on what you mean by *`it's not working`* ... error message (if yes, provide the full error message), the wrong result (again, provide some details), no result, something else?

Comment: I updated it with a screen capture of the error and code. The error seems pretty generic to me that's why I didn't post it originally. it fails to execute so I figured anyone that looked at the syntax would probably be able to recognize the issue immediately.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into #temp_table select so.name table_name, sc.name column_name
from syscolumns sc
  , sysobjects so
where sc.id = so.id
```

Expand the output column list at your own imperative

Comment: I appreciate the response. The issue I found with this query is it doesn't return all the columns. It appears that columns that aren't standard datatypes aren't included. I'm not familiar with SAP but it seems like there can be custom data types?  When I use sp_columns actually returns all columns.

Answer (score 0):

`WITH OVERVIEW` does not appear to be a part of the [(SAP) SQL Anywhere CALL statement](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_SQL_Anywhere/93079d4ba8e44920ae63ffb4def91f5b/816a6c776ce21014adde84db85cc1774.html) [and I couldn't find anything that comes anywhere close to whatever this is: `( et_result => #ColumnListing)`].

I did find a reference to `WITH OVERVIEW` in the [(SAP) HANA CALL statement](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/20d364c175191014b592f500ccb5510c.html) but (of course) this is not useful in a SQL Anywhere context.

Looking through the [(SAP) SQL Anywhere SQL Reference manual - SQL Statements](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_SQL_Anywhere/93079d4ba8e44920ae63ffb4def91f5b/817a170c6ce21014a294825d88f88f30.html) I couldn't find an exact match on your requirement but I was able to combine the specs for the [INSERT Statement](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_SQL_Anywhere/93079d4ba8e44920ae63ffb4def91f5b/81712f3a6ce21014ada883e2b235cf26.html) + [SELECT Statement](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_SQL_Anywhere/93079d4ba8e44920ae63ffb4def91f5b/3be640936c5f10149013d54460eaabb0.html) + [FROM Clause](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_SQL_Anywhere/93079d4ba8e44920ae63ffb4def91f5b/3be4b5016c5f10149f10a6db96ba7e52.html) to generate this:

```
INSERT into #ColumnListing
select * from sp_columns('CatalogElement')
```

**NOTE:** tested successfully in a `(SAP) SQL Anywhere v 17.0.9.4899` database